# Bootstrap: Grid item not inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a grid of items which are split into two columns using Bootstrap, the columns are collapsed on `SM` and `XS`. I have a visual error on `MD` and `LG` views where the 'Cabling' item has large margins above and below the element.

What is the cause of this behavior?

[Bootply link.](http://www.bootply.com/PDS9ZwtErR)

**HTML:**

```
<h2>Products &amp; Services</h2>

<p>Please see our products and services below</p>

<div class="row grid-headers">

    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-2"><a id="" name="" href="#"><img id="" src="http://baadev-heathrowtelecoms.cs14.force.com/resource/1373023376000/collateral_lan_icon" class="img-responsive" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10"><a id="" name="" href="#">
                <h3>Managed LAN Services</h3></a>          
            <p>
                The Managed LAN service provides a secure, reliable, flexible and inexpensive solution to network your data and IT systems within a given terminal or terminals.  You can connect end station equipment (PCs, printers, servers, workstations) directly to the LAN&#8217;s Ethernet infrastructure and [Redacted] seamlessly facilitates connectivity.              
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-2"><a id="" name="" href="#"><img id="" src="http://baadev-heathrowtelecoms.cs14.force.com/resource/1373023391000/collateral_wlan_icon" class="img-responsive" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10"><a id="" name="" href="#">
                <h3>Managed Wireless Service</h3></a>
            <p>
                [Redacted] Wireless LAN coverage is provided via resilient access points to guarantee coverage even in the event of the failure of a single access point. The infrastructure is also capable of transparent roaming between access points to provide a seamless customer experience. The solution connects mobile workers at [Redacted] to back office systems simply, cost-effectively and securely, wherever they are and in real-time.               
            </p>
        </div>          
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-2"><a id="" name="" href="#"><img id="" src="http://baadev-heathrowtelecoms.cs14.force.com/resource/1373023406000/collateral_telephony_icon" class="img-responsive" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10"><a id="" name="" href="http://baadev-heathrowtelecoms.cs14.force.com/resource/1373024567000/collateral_telephony">
                <h3>Telephony</h3></a>          
            <p>
                [Redacted] Airport will provide a common telephony platform for customers using either a Cisco IP Phone or by providing Analogue connectivity. Phones include, standard phone, enhanced phone, expansion module, conferencing phone as well as an analogue line (includes analogue handset).
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-2"><a id="" name="" href="#"><img id="" src="http://baadev-heathrowtelecoms.cs14.force.com/resource/1373023422000/collateral_iptv_icon" class="img-responsive" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10"><a id="" name="" href="#">
                <h3>IPTV</h3></a>          
            <p>     
                [Redacted] provides an extensible digital media solution delivering television service in HD (High Definition) and non-HD formats. We offer Freeview as standard and Sky channels as an option. IPTV can be delivered via [Redacted] provided screens (various sizes) or Customer provided screens.                     
            </p>
        </div>          
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-2"><a id="" name="" href="#"><img id="" src="http://baadev-heathrowtelecoms.cs14.force.com/resource/1373023471000/collateral_cctv_icon" class="img-responsive" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10"><a id="" name="" href="#">
                <h3>Closed Circuit Television (CCTV)</h3></a>          
            <p> 
                CCTV is a key business tool which supports both operational and security requirements. CCTV enables multiple agencies to collaborating effectively in addressing operational and security requirements as well as supporting single commercial requirements from airlines, retailers and associated companies e.g. ground handlers.                         
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-2"><a id="" name="" href="#"><img id="" src="http://baadev-heathrowtelecoms.cs14.force.com/resource/1373023440000/collateral_fids_icon" class="img-responsive" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10"><a id="" name="" href="#">
                <h3>Flight Information Display System (FIDS)</h3></a>          
            <p>             
                Flight Information Display System is available airport-wide and compatible with all existing and any new Airport Operational DataBases. This solution enables improvements in the areas of wayfinding, contributing to a better passenger travel experience.                
            </p>
        </div>          
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-2"><a id="" name="" href="#"><img id="" src="http://baadev-heathrowtelecoms.cs14.force.com/resource/1373023456000/collateral_sis_icon" class="img-responsive" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10"><a id="" name="" href="#">
                <h3>Staff Information Systems</h3></a>          
            <p>         
                [Redacted]&#8217;s SIS solution enables flight data to be individually configured and made available on demand. Access to SIS is based upon an annual licence fee and can be viewed via the internet or as a PC based application. Service can be provided over the current [Redacted] airport network.                   
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-2"><img id="" src="http://baadev-heathrowtelecoms.cs14.force.com/resource/1373023488000/collateral_cabling_icon" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <h3>Cabling</h3>
            <p>     
                If you decide not to use our managed LAN to connect your branches, we can still help by running long-distance fibre links or short distance copper links between them. Our people already have the necessary passes and know the site, so they can solve the often daunting problems of finding a physical route across the airport.                        
            </p>
        </div>          
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-2"><a id="" name="" href="#"><img id="" src="http://baadev-heathrowtelecoms.cs14.force.com/resource/1373023349000/collateral_broadband_icon" class="img-responsive" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10"><a id="" name="" href="#">
                <h3>Broadband</h3></a>          
            <p> 
                The high speed access to Internet is provided at wide range of options in terms of bandwidth, resiliency, and mode of connection, ready to solve all your business needs. The short delivery times and on-site support can&#8217;t be beaten by any other offering.                           
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-2"><a id="" name="" href="#"><img id="" src="http://baadev-heathrowtelecoms.cs14.force.com/resource/1373023265000/collateral_radio_icon" class="img-responsive" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10"><a id="" name="" href="#">
                <h3>Radio</h3></a>          
            <p> 
                [Redacted] operates an MPT1327 analogue Trunk Radio system to provide push to talk voice communication across the [Redacted] campus &#8211; both inside the terminals, and on the airfield.  [Redacted] also operates Common user antenna systems within each of the terminals allowing third party operated radio service providers to provide a similar service within the airport.                           
            </p>
        </div>          
    </div>      

</div>
```

Comment: The problem is with the content in "Closed Circuit Television (CCTV)". The length of that content is more than other column contents length. Just remove some content in this column you find the correct alignment.

Comment: You are nesting columns incorrectly. A `col-*` class must be a child of a `row` class.

Comment: @Stuart Yes, but there are `col-*` inside other `col-*` elements which is not correct. Also missing a `container` wrap too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because not all of your divs are the same height. One or more of your divs is taller than the other and therefore needs to be told to clear to the left.

If you don’t need to support older browsers you could add:

```
.col-md-6:nth-of-type(2n+1){
    clear: left;
}
```

If you do need to support older browsers you could give every odd numbered div a class and use the same CSS:

```
<div class="odd col-md-6 col-xs-12"></div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12"></div>
<div class="odd col-md-6 col-xs-12"></div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12"></div>

.odd{
    clear: left;
}
```

It’s worth noting that you’d have to wrap this in the correct media query though as this would potentially affect your grid at the other Bootstrap breakpoints.

This will work with the default Bootstrap breakpoints:

```
@media (min-width: 992px){
    .col-md-6:nth-of-type(2n+1){
        clear: left;
    }
}
```

Here’s a demo: http://www.bootply.com/weHAys32UR

Answer (score 1):

You have not properly nested your divs. You should ideally keep two divs in one single row which takes full width of the screen. So as mentioned by  @stuart, height of divs creates this problem.

You must not change bootstrap inbuilt classes . For example, adding class with 'row' and change its width , etc.

```
<div class="grid-headers">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="row"> // You need to again nest this
                <div class="col-xs-2"><a id="" name="" href="#"><img id="" src="http://baadev-heathrowtelecoms.cs14.force.com/resource/1373023376000/collateral_lan_icon" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
                <div class="col-xs-10"><a id="" name="" href="#">
                    <h3>Managed LAN Services</h3></a>          
                    <p>
                        The Managed LAN service provides a secure, reliable, flexible and inexpensive solution to network your data and IT systems within a given terminal or terminals.  You can connect end station equipment (PCs, printers, servers, workstations) directly to the LAN&#8217;s Ethernet infrastructure and [Redacted] seamlessly facilitates connectivity.              
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="row"> // You need to again nest this
                <div class="col-xs-2"><a id="" name="" href="#"><img id="" src="http://baadev-heathrowtelecoms.cs14.force.com/resource/1373023376000/collateral_lan_icon" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
                <div class="col-xs-10"><a id="" name="" href="#">
                    <h3>Managed LAN Services</h3></a>          
                    <p>
                        The Managed LAN service provides a secure, reliable, flexible and inexpensive solution to network your data and IT systems within a given terminal or terminals.  You can connect end station equipment (PCs, printers, servers, workstations) directly to the LAN&#8217;s Ethernet infrastructure and [Redacted] seamlessly facilitates connectivity.              
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    /// same as above structure

</div> // ends grid-headers
```

Check my answer : http://www.bootply.com/s4HlAGQLQO
Now, It has nothing to do div's height.

check http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting